# how to access data members of all object arrays

Tags: c++, class, object

let's say I have the following class and the coresponding object array from this class
what should i do to access the data members of all the objects just in one function

```
 class sample
{
    char * data1;
    int data2;
public:
//possible member functions
 };

void main()
{
   sample objs[10];
.....
```

My goal is to compare "data1" of all the object instances from this class . and i might possibly have hundreds of objects

Comment: Stop using 1) pointers, 2) arrays, 3) `void main`. Start using C++.

Comment: I thought pointers were part of C++... maybe he wants to compare pointers to chars, not strings...

Comment: What do you want to compare "data1" of your objects to?

Comment: I want to compare them all to some data which i intend to read from the keyboard

Comment: What is the result of comparison, u r expecting?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Here I am trying to give you a very simple format of my problem. All I want to know is, Is it possible to access all objects data members in one function?

Answer (score 0):

As the data1 member is private, you need getter/setter method to access those. Ofcourse the initialization can be done through constructor. I need more information, like what is the meaning of comparison?, what is the meaning of accessing? etc, to be able to help better.

Comment: In my problem data1 represents a pointer to a very big char bit table. I am trying to compare the bits of manys of these bit table instances with specific bits computed using hash functions. I want to do the comparisons parallely inorder to save execution time. That is why i needed to access all the objects data members at once.

Comment: "I want to do the comparisons parallely inorder to save execution time" - i guess u will multi-thread/precess for this. If you mean all the data1 will be compared in a single expression, then you will not need.

Comment: it is really complicated to explain how I am going to implement the comparison. It would be helpful if you tell me if there is any way to get access to the data members with just the above simple sample code

Comment: Then simply implement public "char* getData1()", and access as objs[0].getData1(). Remember, even if you have a complicated expression involving all data1, the processing will still happen one at a time. I mean if you do "a | b | c", first "a|b" will happen then the result will be or'ed with c. Which is still sequential.

Comment: that is exactly what I am planning to do

Comment: @John So you want to parallelize things? This changes the whole question and is not achievable with one simple line of code.

Comment: @ChristianRau: What do you suggest?